# How to prevent state transition, when there is another transition running in angular ui router?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, angular-promise, angular-transitions

In my angular app, I have this issue. When user quickly double-clicks link to state (ui-sref link), the target state begins loading twice. This would be bearable, if the state window didn't freeze and stop responding to other state changes. When clicking another ui-sref links, URL changes accordingly, http calls on background are made, but the view is frozen.

I need to know, how can I prevent any transition, when there is another transition already trying to resolve promise. I know I can somehow work magic with $stateChangeStart and event.preventDefault(). What I don't know is how to allow my transition to continue after resolving it's resolve block and how to counterpart event.preventDefault().

Thanks for your time. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular UI Router's $state object has a property on it, 'transition', which will be present if it is in the middle of an active transition. One option is to remove the ui-sref attribute and use a ng-click attribute instead. Inside your ng-click function, you can do a manual check for the presence of the transition object before invoking $state.go().

**Before**

HTML:

```
<a ui-sref="Root.State1">
```

**After**

HTML:

```
<a href="" ng-click="goToStateOne()">
```

JS:

```
scope.goToStateOne = function() {
  if (!$state.transition) $state.go('Root.State1');
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot, Jeff. Although it brings a few things to deal with. Before, I was able to use `ui-sref-active="active"` to add css class to active bar. Is there any elegant way to achieve the same functionality with the new approach? The best I came up with, is to use ng-class and add another function to check for current state.

Also is it good idea to create a service so I don't have to define the `goToStateOne()` function many times or is it better to place the definition in the rootscope?